# I want to make the other combobox visible according to the selected country combobox option using react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to make the other combobox visible according to the selected country combobox option using react js. I have two react components that I mentioned below. someone country someone state. I want to make the state visible when USA is selected as the country, otherwise the state column will not be visible. How do I do this? can you help me?

```
           <Col>
                <FormControl as="select"
                             name='country'
                             onChange={props.handleChange}
                             onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                             value={props.values.country}
                             isInvalid={props.touched.country && props.errors.country}
                             maxLength={100}
                             custom>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                </FormControl>
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <FormControl as="select"
                             name='state'
                             onChange={props.handleChange}
                             onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                             value={props.values.state}
                             isInvalid={props.touched.state && props.errors.state}
                             custom>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select State</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                </FormControl>
            </Col>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional rendering:

```
  {country === "United States" &&
        <Col>
            <FormControl as="select"
                         name='state'
                         onChange={props.handleChange}
                         onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                         value={props.values.state}
                         isInvalid={props.touched.state && props.errors.state}
                         custom>
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select State</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                ...
             </FormControl>
        </Col>
   }
```

Comment: Should I write this in the <option> tag? how can i implement it?

Comment: Just enclose your second `<Col>...</Col>` within `{country === "United States" &&`  at the beginning and ` }` at the end